# Remove white space when using display:none on elements in print.css

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

I'm trying to simplify the print view for a client by removing images (and some other elements) however, this leaves some huge white gaps between the other elements in the print view.

Does anyone have any ideas on how i can decrease the white space between the Names of the speakers, just to condense it down? The current css used is:

```
@media print{
       .prog a{display:none;}
       #main img, .news {display:none;}
       .prog .span8 .row-fluid {margin-bottom:0;}
        #footer ul {display:none;}
}
```

The print view can be found 
[here][1] by clicking the print button.

It isn't really an option to add more elements into the html as each speaker/name is contained within its own K2 article as this is a list view.

I'd be happy for any suggestions?
Regards
D

Comment: Did you mean the additional white page at the end of the file?

Comment: No, the huge white gaps between the peoples names. If the end page could be removed also, that would be a bonus. :)

Comment: @Dtorr1981: removing white space at the end of a printed document when content won't fill the whole page can only be achieved by taking a scissor and cutting the paper, just below the end of the printed content ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your print view is working fine but you need to revise your content to remove extraneous `<p> </p>` and `<h4> </h4>` blocks.

Instead of this format for each speaker:

```
<h4>
  Sasja Beslik
  <img src="/images/conference/speakers/Sasja_Beslik.jpg" alt="Sasja Beslik" />
</h4>
<h4>
  <em>
    <span class="cred">
      Head of Sustainable Finance - Nordea Wealth Management - Sweden
      <a href="[LINK]">Linkedin</a>
    </span>
  </em>
</h4>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Try this or something similar:

```
<h4 style="clear: both;">
  Sasja Beslik
  <img src="/images/conference/speakers/Sasja_Beslik.jpg" alt="Sasja Beslik" />
  <em>
    <span class="cred">
      Head of Sustainable Finance - Nordea Wealth Management - Sweden
      <a href="[LINK]">Linkedin</a>
    </span>
  </em>
</h4>
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, I thought as much - each speaker is in a separate article thus this would be extremely time consuming. Those darn built in editors can be a pain. I'll speak to my client and see what he says, its easily a couple of hours work to update them all manually.